# How to add only one currency for paypal payment

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, yii2

I am integrating PayPal with one of my websites but the problem is that they want Indian customers to pay in INR only but it is actually complicating things.

The way I am integrating PayPal in my website is taken from the question which is described over here.

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/yii2-paypal-integration/126032

But when Indian customers are trying to pay using USD the payment fails how can I avoid this problem I just want only one currency implementation in my website

Comment: this is too broad question you have to enable multi-currency settings first of all in you paypal account also your account should be setup as a bank account read this thread https://forum.manager.io/t/multi-currency-paypal-account-issue/14975

Comment: I got this from paypal support `Unfortunately domestic transaction is not possible to receive in USD and similarly  international transaction should be in USD.

There is no way to have single currency for both the transactions.

Thanks and regards,`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Dotplant2 which uses Yii2 and currency conversion tables in the backend.  Specifically these files.

1. components/payment/[PaypalPayment.php](https://github.com/DevGroup-ru/dotplant2/blob/master/application/components/payment/PayPalPayment.php)  and 2. their [CurrencyHelper.php](https://github.com/DevGroup-ru/dotplant2/blob/master/application/modules/shop/helpers/CurrencyHelper.php) at modules/shop/helpers. Here are some code snippets.

PaypalPayment

```
public function content()
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $this->order;
        $order->calculate();

        $payer = (new Payer())->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $priceSubTotal = 0;
        /** @var ItemList $itemList */
        $itemList = array_reduce($order->items, function($result, $item) use (&$priceSubTotal) {
            /** @var OrderItem $item */
            /** @var Product $product */
            $product = $item->product;
            $price = CurrencyHelper::convertFromMainCurrency($item->price_per_pcs, $this->currency);
            $priceSubTotal = $priceSubTotal + ($price * $item->quantity);

            /** @var ItemList $result */
            return $result->addItem(
                (new Item())
                    ->setName($product->name)
                    ->setCurrency($this->currency->iso_code)
                    ->setPrice($price)
                    ->setQuantity($item->quantity)
                    ->setUrl(Url::toRoute([
                        '@product',
                        'model' => $product,
                        'category_group_id' => $product->category->category_group_id
                    ], true))
            );
        }, new ItemList());

        $priceTotal = CurrencyHelper::convertFromMainCurrency($order->total_price, $this->currency);

        $details = (new Details())
            ->setShipping($priceTotal - $priceSubTotal)
            ->setSubtotal($priceSubTotal)
            ->setTax(0);

        $amount = (new Amount())
            ->setCurrency($this->currency->iso_code)
            ->setTotal($priceTotal)
            ->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = (new Transaction())
            ->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription($this->transactionDescription)
            ->setInvoiceNumber($this->transaction->id);

        $urls = (new RedirectUrls())
            ->setReturnUrl($this->createResultUrl(['id' => $this->order->payment_type_id]))
            ->setCancelUrl($this->createFailUrl());

        $payment = (new Payment())
            ->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction])
            ->setRedirectUrls($urls);

        $link = null;
        try {
            $link = $payment->create($this->apiContext)->getApprovalLink();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $link = null;
        }

        return $this->render('paypal', [
            'order' => $order,
            'transaction' => $this->transaction,
            'approvalLink' => $link,
        ]);
    }
```

CurrencyHelper

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\shop\helpers;

use app\modules\shop\models\Currency;
use app\modules\shop\models\UserPreferences;

class CurrencyHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Currency $userCurrency
     * @var Currency $mainCurrency
     */
    static protected $userCurrency = null;
    static protected $mainCurrency = null;

    /**
     * @return Currency
     */
    static public function getUserCurrency()
    {
        if (null === static::$userCurrency) {
            static::$userCurrency = static::findCurrencyByIso(UserPreferences::preferences()->userCurrency);
        }

        return static::$userCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * @param Currency $userCurrency
     * @return Currency
     */
    static public function setUserCurrency(Currency $userCurrency)
    {
        return static::$userCurrency = $userCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * @return Currency
     */
    static public function getMainCurrency()
    {
        return null === static::$mainCurrency
            ? static::$mainCurrency = Currency::getMainCurrency()
            : static::$mainCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param bool|true $useMainCurrency
     * @return Currency
     */
    static public function findCurrencyByIso($code)
    {
        $currency = Currency::find()->where(['iso_code' => $code])->one();
        $currency = null === $currency ? static::getMainCurrency() : $currency;
        return $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param float|int $input
     * @param Currency $from
     * @param Currency $to
     * @return float|int
     */
    static public function convertCurrencies($input = 0, Currency $from, Currency $to)
    {
        if (0 === $input) {
            return $input;
        }

        if ($from->id !== $to->id) {
            $main = static::getMainCurrency();
            if ($main->id === $from->id && $main->id !== $to->id) {
                $input = $input / $to->convert_rate * $to->convert_nominal;
            } elseif ($main->id !== $from->id && $main->id === $to->id) {
                $input = $input / $from->convert_nominal * $from->convert_rate;
            } else {
                $input = $input / $from->convert_nominal * $from->convert_rate;
                $input = $input / $to->convert_rate * $to->convert_nominal;
            }
        }

        return $to->formatWithoutFormatString($input);
    }

    /**
     * @param float|int $input
     * @param Currency $from
     * @return float|int
     */
    static public function convertToUserCurrency($input = 0, Currency $from)
    {
        return static::convertCurrencies($input, $from, static::getUserCurrency());
    }

    /**
     * @param float|int $input
     * @param Currency $from
     * @return float|int
     */
    static public function convertToMainCurrency($input = 0, Currency $from)
    {
        return static::convertCurrencies($input, $from, static::getMainCurrency());
    }

    /**
     * @param float|int $input
     * @param Currency $to
     * @return float|int
     */
    static public function convertFromMainCurrency($input = 0, Currency $to)
    {
        return static::convertCurrencies($input, static::getMainCurrency(), $to);
    }

    /**
     * @param Currency $currency
     * @param string|null $locale
     * @return string
     */
    static public function getCurrencySymbol(Currency $currency, $locale = null)
    {
        $locale = null === $locale ? \Yii::$app->language : $locale;

        $result = '';
        try {
            $fake = $locale . '@currency=' . $currency->iso_code;
            $fmt = new \NumberFormatter($fake, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
            $result = $fmt->getSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = preg_replace('%[\d\s,]%i', '', $currency->format(0));
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this from PayPal support:

> Unfortunately domestic transaction is not possible to receive in USD and similarly international transaction should be in USD. There is no way to have single currency for both the transactions. Thanks and regards,